# What does it mean when GitHub commit says "in the future"?

Tags: github, commit

We are working as a globally team on this project.

This last commit shows "**in the future**". We wonder what this even means?

Here's the screenshot (observe the top most commit):

[image: what does it means when GitHub commit says in the future]

We should get the timestamp instead of this, right?

Comment: see the image  in the link for details

Answer (score 2):

Git embeds two timestamps in every commit: the author timestamp and the committer timestamp.  Usually on GitHub, this is the committer timestamp that you're seeing.

However, nothing requires that the timestamp be accurate.  In this case, the timestamp or the timezone that's part of it are incorrect and the time specified is in the future.  This probably means that the computer on which the commit was made has an incorrect timezone setting or is not properly synced to a reliable NTP server to get the current time.

In fact, you can synthesize any timestamp you want in Git, including ones before Git was created or well after we'll all be dead.  See the `GIT_AUTHOR_TIMESTAMP` and `GIT_COMMITTER_TIMESTAMP` variables in `git-commit(1)`.